# NumPy fancy indexing with provided output array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a two-dimensional array and index it with a pair of arrays (in fact my arrays are much larger, millions of elements):

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
b = a[[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0]]
```

Indexing will allocate a new array. Is there a way to do this indexing with an output array provided?

I looked at `np.take` and `np.choose`, but it seems that they don't work with a pair of arrays. I managed to use `np.take(..., out=buf)` if I ravel the array and manually construct the 1-d instance, but it causes more memory accesses, and almost kills the improvement over eliminating allocation for the indexing result.

Comment: What's the nature of this `buf`?

Comment: `buf` is a temporary array of the size matching the result of indexing. In practice I do this indexing applied to several arrays and I'd like to reuse the memory allocated to store the result of indexing.

Comment: `buf[:]=a[...]`?  How are you measuring improvement?

Comment: Hmm. Will `buf[:]=a[...]` not do the temporary allocation to store the array on rhs? (I did some `timeit` tests, they were inconclusive)

Comment: @VadimKantorov. It's memory test that you need. To evaluate `a[...]`, numpy creates a temp array.

Comment: do you have one index (pair of arrays) and several large arrays to index, or one single large array and several index pairs?

Comment: not an answer to your question, but could help with your code efficiency: numpy is very efficient for allocating memory up to some limit. I guess it reuse pre-allocated memory. So if your operation use more than this limit and trigger a real allocation, you might get much better result by "simply" splitting the operation in a couple of sub-operations. E.g. process 1st half of you indices, then the 2nd half.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked a long time ago, but just in case:

If your large array (`a` in your question) is C-contiguous, then you could use [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) instead of `np.ravel()` as in your question. That returns a view of the large array, without copying, and is very fast. You can then use `np.take()` with an existing `out=...` destination.

Note however that, in your question, the index pair itself is large (twice as many elements as the output you seek). If we convert it to a 1-d index (with `np.ravel_multi_index(ix, a.shape)` as below), that is also a new array of the same size as the output you want, so in the end you might not save much time not memory.

In any case, here is one use of `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`:

```py
n = np.prod(a.shape)
as1d_view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (n, ), writeable=False)

# then, to index and copy into buf:
np.take(as1d_view, np.ravel_multi_index(ix, a.shape), out=buf)
```

**Example 1: single large array, multiple indices**

```py
# setup
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
indices = [
    (np.array([0, 0, 0, 1]), np.array([0, 1, 2, 0])),
    (np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]), np.array([2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0])),
    (np.array([0, 0, 1]), np.array([0, 1, 2])),
]

# init
n = np.prod(a.shape)
as1d_view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (n, ), writeable=False)
m = max(len(ix[0]) for ix in indices)
buf = np.empty(m, dtype=a.dtype)

# loop
for i, ix in enumerate(indices):
    m = len(ix[0])
    np.take(as1d_view, np.ravel_multi_index(ix, a.shape), out=buf[:m])
    print(f'for index {i}, buf={buf[:m]!r}')

# gives:
# for index 0, buf=array([1, 2, 3, 4])
# for index 1, buf=array([3, 5, 2, 6, 1, 4])
# for index 2, buf=array([1, 2, 6])
```

**Example 2: single index, multiple large arrays**

```py
# setup (presumably the large arrays are obtained one at a time instead...)
a_list = [
    np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]),
    np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5),
    np.random.randint(0, 20, (4,4)),
]
ix = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1]), np.array([0, 1, 2, 0])

# init
m = len(ix[0])
buf = np.empty(m, dtype=a.dtype)

# loop
for i, a in enumerate(a_list):
    ix1d = np.ravel_multi_index(ix, a.shape)
    as1d_view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, (n, ), writeable=False)
    np.take(as1d_view, ix1d, out=buf)
    print(f'for array {i}, buf={buf!r}')

# gives:
# for array 0, buf=array([1, 2, 3, 4])
# for array 1, buf=array([0, 1, 2, 5])
# for array 2, buf=array([ 5, 19,  1,  3])
```

Comment: Will `np.ravel_multi_index(...)` trigger an allocation itself (for the index tensor)?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title question, you can output the lookup into an existing array:

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()

# some array
W = 20000
a = rng.uniform(0,1, (W,W))

# lookup indices
S=100000000
i = rng.integers(0, W, (2, S)).astype(int)

result = np.zeros(S) # to store lookup output
result[:] = a[i[0,:], i[1,:]] # <--------- NumPy fancy indexing with provided output array
```

However, if the size of the lookup (S) is big this can become very slow. On my computer:

```
%timeit result[:] = a[i[0,:], i[1,:]]
# 6.57 s ± 181 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

This is in part because memory allocation takes time. So you can take advantage of the fact that numpy manages very efficently memory up to some size (probably it keeps and re-uses some memory for "little" operation). Note that while executing the above timeit, which repeat the operation, I can see the used memory on my computer going up and down

So by splitting the lookup, you can reduce to total time and ram numpy uses:

```
step = int(S/2)
%timeit for s in range(0, S2, step): result[s:s+step] = a[i[0,s:s+step], i[1,s:s+step]]
# 3.46 s ± 99.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

step = int(S/10)
%timeit for s in range(0, S2, step): result[s:s+step] = a[i[0,s:s+step], i[1,s:s+step]]
# 3.38 s ± 84.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Here splitting the lookup in 2 steps reduces the total time by 2. However, it doesn't do much splitting in more steps. Note that the above timeit doesn't show much move on my computer used memory.

The best splitting step will probably depend on your computer, or maybe some python configuration that I don't know of. My computer has 32GB of ram, so maybe a 100million item array is not that big.

So just try with your computer and use case.

Two ending notes:

1. first in my code above to split lookup, be careful about using proper indices on the end border. I am not sure it ends exactly rigth
2. Don't spend time on premature optimization. I know it's tempting some time to optimize what we think could be optimized, but don't spend too much of your human time to reduce a couple of seconds of your computer cpu time :)